Entity Framework: Same foreign key for different entities
I have 2 models which look like this:
public class TLSlide
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Uid { get; set; }
    public required TLDate start_date { get; set; }
    public TLDate? end_date { get; set; }
}

public class TLDate
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Uid { get; set; }
    public required int year { get; set; }

    // Foreign Key Properties
    public Guid? StartDateId { get; set; }
    public Guid? EndDateId { get; set; }
    public Guid? StartDateEraId { get; set; }
    public Guid? EndDateEraId { get; set; }
}

The relationship is defined like this:
            modelBuilder.Entity<TLSlide>()
            .HasOne(t => t.start_date)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<TLDate>(d => d.StartDateId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<TLSlide>()
            .HasOne(t => t.end_date)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<TLDate>(d => d.EndDateId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

So TLDate is dependant on TLSlide. If TLSlide is deleted, the related TLDates should also be deleted. My Code works, but looks terrible. Can I use the same FK for start_date  and end_date? Or do I need to specify an independant FK like I did?

Yes, two FKs, although SQL Server won't allow both to be cascading.

Ok, then I am doing it right. Maybe I just have to use better names ;). As for the SQL Server: Interesting, the documentation has some more infos on that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete
